# Odd behavior in twig evaluating variable

Tags: shopware6

```
    {% if item["extensions"]["my_plugin_extension"]["description"] is empty %}
    empty -
{% else %}
    not empty -
{% endif %}
{% if item["extensions"]["my_plugin_extension"]["description"] is null %}
    null -
{% else %}
    not null -
{% endif %}
{% if item["extensions"]["my_plugin_extension"]["description"] is defined %}
    defined -
{% else %}
    not defined -
{% endif %}
```

where content of the item["extensions"] looks like

```
{ "my_plugin_extension": { "promotionId": "018d5b238e6479e88d0d341d943aae8e", "mediaId": "018b865c7b897028b477b618f44f446c", "description": "voopar", "createdAt": "2024-02-01T06:03:48.297+00:00", "updatedAt": "2024-02-01T06:04:08.544+00:00" } }
```

gives the output

**empty - null - defined -**

in my admin twig. what could be the reason for such behavior? the results should logically be "not empty - not null - defined". what do i miss?

right now i test the example for compatibility with sw 6.5.6.1

Comment: The admin uses only the block and parent syntax from twig, everything else needs to be done with vue templating, so you need to use v-if for that example.